# modx evolution get template value from resource object

Tags: modx, modx-evolution

I am using modx evo 1.0.2.
I have resource id. Now i wanted to get a template var of this resource.

I have array of resource ids. I am getting resource by its id like this:

```
 $objResource =  $modx->getDocumentObject('id',$arrPage['id']);
```

Now i want to get a template variable of this resource. I have tried like this:

```
$objResource->getTemplateVarOutput('TempVarName');
```

it was not working. What will be the proper way to get tvValue from a specific resource?

Any suggestion will be helpful .

Thanks

Comment: 1.0.2 is very old, you should really look at upgrading to the most recent version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$modx->getTemplateVarOutput(array('TempVarName'), $arrPage['id']);
```

http://wiki.modxcms.com/index.php/API:getTemplateVarOutput